# How to express in JS regex any of "iPhone10,3", "iPhone10,6", "iPhone11,2", "iPhone11,4", "iPhone11,8"

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanna handle iOS Internal Name.
I wanna check in JS if `const type` is equal to any of

```
"iPhone10,3", "iPhone10,6", "iPhone11,2", "iPhone11,4", "iPhone11,8"
```

.

I wanna express this in the shortest way, but it is a little complicated.

Is

```
type.match(/^iPhone(10\,[36]|11\,\d)$/)
```

the shortest?

Comment: You don't have to escape comma in regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow only these 5 specific possible values, you should restrict the subversions of the iPhone 11 as well:

```
^iPhone(10,[36]|11,[248])$
```

Comment: I think this should work too `/^iPhone1(0,[36]|1,[248])/`